# Explanation of template statement in Caffe2 InputIsType method

Tags: templates, caffe2

The Caffe2 framework includes the following code in the file [`caffe2/core/operator.h`](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/core/operator.h):

```
  template <typename T>
  inline bool InputIsType(int idx) {
     return inputs_.at(idx)->template IsType<T>();
  }
```

I do not understand the third line of this code snippet: why is the `template` statement used here? To my knowledge, `template` is always followed by `<>` and used to define a type `T`, like in the first line of this code snippet.

Why do we need to write `template` before calling `IsType<T>()`?

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly: you ask what the part `template IsType<T>()` means?

Comment: @hbaderts yes, what the part template IsType<T>() means

Comment: does my answer clarify your question? As you see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), you can accept the answer if you believe this is the solution to your problem. Otherwise, please leave a comment on what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InputIsType` method is part of the `OperatorBase` class, which is the base class of all operators in Caffe2. Each operator contains (among others) the following private fields (defined in [`caffe2/core/operator.h`](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/core/operator.h)):

```
vector<const Blob*> inputs_;
vector<Blob*> outputs_;
```

These are the inputs and outputs of your operator. As an operator can have multiple inputs and/or multiple outputs, both are vectors.

The `InputIsType` method takes an input `int idx`, which defines which input Blob to look at (i.e. `InputIsType(0)` is the zero'th input Blob, and so on) and compares the type of that specific Blob to the type `<T>`. This is done using the `IsType` method of the `Blob` class, which is defined in [`caffe2/core/blob.h`](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/core/blob.h):

```
/**
 * Checks if the content stored in the blob is of type T.
 */
template <class T>
bool IsType() const { return meta_.Match<T>(); }
```

*Note: This matches the type `T` to the type of our Blob. I won't go into details on how that works. Let's just assume this returns `True` or `False` as required.*

So, to check if a Blob `A` has type `int`, we would have to call

```
A->IsType<int>();
```

However, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/4221706), the compiler doesn't know whether you want to use the template with `<int>` here, or whether you are doing a comparison with the `<` (less than) sign. So we must tell the compiler we are using templates here, and call

```
A->template IsType<int>();
```

The same applies in the case of the `InputIsType` method: instead of using `int` in this example, we use the type `T` (which we defined before), and call `IsType` on element `idx` of the vector `inputs_`:

```
inputs_.at(idx)->template IsType<T>();
```

Comment: could you give an example to show A->IsType <int>(), < is less than, > is bigger than? I understand the case boost::function <int()> f; boost::function is a number. i do not understand A->IsType is a number less than T which is maybe also a number. A->IsType < T maybe return true and then true > () is nonsense. i think parser can't parse T as a number.

Comment: The *less than* and *bigger than* example is just an example how there can be ambiguity. In this case it is not exactly the same, but the idea is the same: you need to write `template` to explicitly tell the compiler that you want to call `IsType` for the type `T`.